# Conditionally load Fancybox resources with Yepnope.js

Tags: jquery, fancybox, yepnope

I'm trying to conditionally load Fancybox js and css code and execute it on an element only if the element is present and I'm in a particular page.
So far I've been trying the following code:

```
yepnope({
test : jQuery('body').hasClass('edizioni'),
yep  : ['/assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css','/assets/js/libs/jquery.fancybox.pack.js','/assets/js/libs/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js',
        jQuery("#gallery a").fancybox()]
});
```

I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox'`

I guess jquery is functioning ok and the resources jquery.fancybox.pack.js gets loaded properly. What's wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the callback feature of yepnope. The way you have it now, it tries to execute `jQuery("#gallery a").fancybox()` at the same time as requesting the `fancybox.pack.js`. It doesn't load the files sequentially. The callback is triggered each time a resource is loaded, you'll need to verify the URL.

This should work, or get you started at least:

```
yepnope({
    test : jQuery('body').hasClass('edizioni'),
    yep  : ['/assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css','/assets/js/libs/jquery.fancybox.pack.js','/assets/js/libs/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js'],
    callback: function (url, result, key) {
        if(url === "/assets/js/libs/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"){
            // Fancybox has loaded, it's safe to call it now
            jQuery("#gallery a").fancybox();
        }
    }
});
```